# I am not able to build the job in jenkins,,,even I had given the path for github

Tags: java, github, jenkins

I am new to jenkins and I was trying to create a job in jenkins. I had pushed my project to github and had supplied the path of github server to jenkins but when I am trying to build the job it is showing an error and not geting build....please help in solving that...

This is the exception that I am getting---

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\hp\.jenkins\jobs\Spring\workspace
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url git@github.com:rishi1020/SpringMVC # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:rishi1020/SpringMVC
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:rishi1020/SpringMVC +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:rishi1020/SpringMVC
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:735)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:983)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1016)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1282)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:rishi1020/SpringMVC +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1591)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1379)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:324)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:733)
... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect , it could be due to git is not configured properly in Jenkins.

Go to Manage Jenkins - > configuration, git configuration should be something like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like a valid Github repository URL.

Use this as your repository URL:
https://github.com/rishi1020/SpringMVC.git

Comment: i am using ssh public key

Comment: Look here and test the connection and if the host is accepted accordingly: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: A whole tutorial is here: http://www.nerdnuts.com/2014/06/jenkins-managing-ssh-keys/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that is because your jenkins server is not able to comunicate with Github with the SSH key pair you provided.

Before your jenkins can pull code from Github to build, you first must ensure that below git command can work well in your command line.

```
cd C:\Users\hp\.jenkins\jobs\Spring\workspace
git clone git@github.com:rishi1020/SpringMVC
```

After above command can work well, then you can go back to jenkins to continue.